# Bower does not install component

Tags: bower

Here's the command I run

```
c:\projectname\www>bower install jquery --save
bower cloning git://github.com/components/jquery.git
bower cached git://github.com/components/jquery.git
bower fetching jquery
bower checking out jquery#1.9.1
bower copying C:\Users\jesse\AppData\Roaming\bower\cache\jquery\cf68c4c4e7507c8d20fee7b5f26709d9
bower installing jquery#1.9.1
```

Here's my component.json

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "directory" : "scripts/components"
}
```

I expected to find something in `c:\projectname\www\scripts\components` but nothing appeared.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, it's worth noting that I tried running the same command before adding the `directory` property to my `component.json` file and nothing appeared in the `components` directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So it turns out that using a `component.json` file is not the correct thing to do.

I created a `.bowerrc` file with

```
{
  "directory" : "scripts/components"
}
```

And it worked like a charm.

Comment: Also, try reading the docs next time, it's succinctly explained here: https://github.com/twitter/bower#configuration

Comment: I actually did read the docs :P. The thing that really threw me off is that I was installing this component into an existing application.  The docs say `All package contents are installed in the components directory by default. You should never directly modify the contents of this directory.` However, it actually installs the component into `app/components`.  I had so many folders in the website already that I didn't notice that bower created the `app` directory, I was just looking for `components`.